# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying a dynamic SQL query but I'm getting an error about conversion but can't figure out what the problem is.

Here's my query :

```
DECLARE @VarSubCriBusqueda VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @VarSubCriBusqueda = 'Marca'

DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @InputString = '%'

SELECT 
    Marcas.MarcaID, Marcas.Marca, Clases.ClaseNo, Marcas.Codigo, Propietarios.Propietario
FROM 
    Marcas 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Propietarios ON marcas.PropietarioID = Propietarios.PropietarioID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Clases ON Marcas.ClaseIntID = clases.ClaseID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Clientes ON Clientes.ClienteID = Marcas.ClienteID
WHERE 
    CASE @VarSubCriBusqueda
        WHEN 'Clases.ClaseNo'
            THEN Clases.ClaseNo
        WHEN 'Codigo'
            THEN Codigo
        WHEN 'Propietarios.Propietario'
            THEN Propietarios.Propietario
        WHEN 'Clientes.Empresa'
            THEN Clientes.Empresa
        WHEN 'Contacto'
            THEN Marcas.Contacto
        WHEN 'Marca'
            THEN Marca
    END LIKE @InputString
```

It end with the following message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ACADEMY AWARDS' to data type int.

Any help?

Comment: What is your `WHERE` clause supposed to be doing?  Most likely, a `CASE` expression is not what you need there.

Comment: Please add the DDL for the tables to your question so that we can see the data types involved.

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood. you are missing the fact that a `case` expression returns a single type.  And, if any of the `then` or `else` clauses are numbers, then *all* are converted to numbers.  I imagine that one or more of the columns are numbers.  One fix is explicit conversion.

A better fix is to get rid of the `case` expression entirely:

```
WHERE (@VarSubCriBusqueda = 'Clases.ClaseNo' AND Clases.ClaseNo like @InputString) OR
      (@VarSubCriBusqueda = 'Codigo' AND Codigo like @InputString) OR
       . . .
```

And even with this formulation, you should use the correct comparison for your type.  So, if you have a number, `LIKE` doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: @Threadw Reference: [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help . I implemented your fix and is working flawlessly.